# SQLite Selecting Average By Day While Excluding Some Hours

Tags: sqlite

I have some code that selects the average by day of a list like this:

```
2015-11-09 09:45:34.038000 | 10
2015-11-09 10:00:34.039000 | 5
```

So, if those were the only two entries 11-09 would be 7.5.  My SQLite query works, but I have another wrinkle, I would like to add.  Here is what I have so far:

```
queryCurs.execute('''select strftime('%m-%d-%Y', date), round(Avg(number),2) from tableA join tableB on tableB.name = tableA.name   where place like ? group by strftime('%m-%d-%Y', date)''', (list[i],))
```

And this works really well.  However, I would like to only include the entries that occur between 8a and 8p.  How would I go about excluding anything that does fall in that range into my average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the time from the timestamp with the [time() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), and filter on it.
(And a simpler way of extracting the date is with the date() function.)

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%d-%Y', date),
       round(Avg(number),2)
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB USING (name)
WHERE place LIKE ?
  AND time(date) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00'
GROUP BY date(date)
```